# SciPy import error when try to import spline

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, python-3.6

Error lines I got:

```
    from scipy.interpolate import spline
ImportError: cannot import name 'spline'
```

The source code cause the issue is :

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
```

I have tried a couple of ways to install `scipy`:

- conda using `conda install scipy`
- install from PyCharm
  [image]
  But none of them are working. Does anything know what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spline` is not in the `scipy.interpolate` module. You could use `splrep` or `UnivariateSpline` instead. Take a look at the available functions in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#module-scipy.interpolate).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did research and found that `spline` was removed from version `1.3.1` and i rollback to `1.2.1` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
f1 = interp1d(x, y, kind='nearest')
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='zero')
f3 = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')

xnew = np.linspace(0, 10, num=1001, endpoint=True)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f1(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--', xnew, f3(xnew), ':')
plt.legend(['data', 'nearest', 'zero', 'quadratic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```